# ASP script to click html button

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, runatserver

Im not a asp developer, i normally do java but trying to modify a script.

I have a button element that has a class called `.loginButton'

I want to programatically click this button.

In Javascript I would do something like this:

```
var buttonIds = document.getElementsByClassName('loginButton');
                var button = buttonIds[0];
                button.click();
```

But I noticed on this file at the top it says `<script runat=server>` so i dont think the javascript way will work.

Appreciate the help.

Thanks

Edit:

`void Page()
    {

```
        string user = Request.QueryString["MY_USER"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user))
        {
            webLogin.user = user;

            TextBox pass = webLogin.FindControl("myPassword") as TextBox;
            if (pass != null)
            {
                string myPassword = Request.QueryString["MY_USER"];

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myPassword))
                {
                    pass.Attributes["Value"] = myPassword;
                }
    Added code here -->     var buttonIds = document.getElementsByClassName('loginButton');
                var button = buttonIds[0];
                button.click();

            }

}`
```

Here is the button

`<div>
                        <asp:Button ID="myLoginButton" runat="server" Text="Log In"
                 " CssClass="loginButton"
                            meta:ResourceKey="loginResource" />
                    </div>`

Comment: The code you posted is javascript. Inside `<script runat=server>` you will need to write either C# or VB code. We need more information in order to help you.

Comment: Javascript can submit asp.net forms (they're forms after all), but whether you want to do it client side depends on what you're trying to achieve. Javascript clicking a login button seems .... odd

Comment: I see this at the top `<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#"`

Comment: The script right now auto-populates the username and password of the form...so just trying to trigger the button to login automatically

Comment: If you're trying to write code to click a button in the UI of a webpage, that would be JavaScript code.  (*Server-side* code can't click a *client-side* button.)  Just like what you have.  Have you put it in a non-server `script` block?  What have you tried and how did it not work as expected?

Comment: @DocHoliday: `"The script right now auto-populates the username and password of the form...so just trying to trigger the button to login automatically"` - Wait... If the server-side code *already has* the information it needs for the operation you want it to perform, then why show a page to the client at all?  Why not just perform that operation right away?

Comment: The `<script runat=server>` tag is designed to hold `c#` code that is processed before the page is served.  You can still add regular JavaScript to the page.

Comment: @David added the function that is currently used.  The 3 lines I added are an attempt to click the login button.  It does not work.  Again, Im not a c#,asp,vb developer so I'm looking at this code for the first time.

Comment: Do you want to call the button click event on the server side or the client side?

Comment: Client...I just want the button clicked after the username and pass placed in the text boxes...the latter is happening with the script above

Comment: @Doc - I think everyone realizes that.  But you have JavaScript mixed in with C#.  So it's hard to determine exactly what you want to do.  Do you want to raise the button click event from the client or the server?

Comment: How about this @ClintB..How do i raise it in c#..since thats the code in the function :)

Comment: @DocHoliday: To answer that you need to first define what the button click actually *does*.  If it calls some function somewhere, then you can also just call that same function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21327704/difference-between-script-tag-with-and-without-runat-server-attribute?rq=1

Comment: this will

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189037/calling-server-side-event-from-html-button-control

Answer (score 0):

You can't just put two different languages together like that.  Regardless of what languages they are or what languages you're familiar with, no two different programming languages can just be mixed in a single code block.

You have JavaScript code, put it in a JavaScript block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var buttonIds = document.getElementsByClassName('loginButton');
    var button = buttonIds[0];
    button.click();
</script>
```

Just put that at the bottom of the page (or anywhere after the `loginButton` that it's looking for, really).

Comment: I understand that..I was looking for how to do it in the script I posted...i will try moving it to the bottom as well to see if it works

Comment: @DocHoliday: "How to do it" might be a bit of a broad term here. If what you're looking to do is literally click a button, then you need to understand the difference between server-side and client-side code. Server-side code executes, builds a response, then sends the whole response to the client. At that point the server-side code is *done*. It can't click a button that (1) doesn't exist yet when it's running and (2) is rendered on a completely different computer (the client). If, however, you're looking to *perform an operation* that the button performs, you might be able to do that.